# ride editor and context help - not exist

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

Editor RIDE does not display help for keywords example "Open browser" in the console is an error message:

```
"Adding keyword 'click_element' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'wait_until_page_contains' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'wait_until_page_contains' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'get_window_titles' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'locator_should_match_x_times' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'get_window_identifiers' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'open_browser' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'wait_until_element_is_visible' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'table_footer_should_contain' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'wait_until_page_does_not_contain' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'input_text_into_alert' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'set_window_size' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'textfield_should_contain' to library 'Selenium2Library' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'select_window' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'element_text_should_be' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
Adding keyword 'wait_until_element_does_not_contain' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
"
```

Install python and library:

```
Package                         Version
------------------------------- -----------
numpy                           1.16.6
Pillow                          6.2.2
pip                             19.2.3
Pygments                        2.5.2
PyMySQL                         0.10.0
PyPubSub                        3.3.0
pywin32                         228
robotframework                  3.2.1
robotframework-databaselibrary  1.2.4
robotframework-pythonlibcore    2.1.0
robotframework-ride             1.7.4.2
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  4.5.0
selenium                        3.141.0
setuptools                      41.2.0
six                             1.15.0
urllib3                         1.25.10
wxPython                        4.0.7.post2
```

How to start the help display after entering the keyword and in the RIDE editor, place the mouse on the word, press CTRL but the info from the keyword not found will be displayed. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you have both SeleniumLibrary and Selenium2Library? In my mind only 1 is needed. So try uninstalling Selenium2Library and restart.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with keywords documentation is fixed in current Beta version of RIDE (2.0b1).

You can install with pip on Python >=3.6 with:

```
pip install -U --pre robotframework-ride
```

Before installing you should see the information on [RIDE project page](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE).